# Flexible images on Outlook

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, outlook, responsiveness

How to make images flexible on Outlook?

I tried with `@media, width:100%, max-width:150px` and other stuff like that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think Outlook supports responsive images, so width:100% won't work here - i found this table useful when designing/building responsive newsletters - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in outlook for @media and max-width: 150% 
but you can use width="100%"

```
<img src="..." width="100%" style="display: block" alt="some alt" />
```